# How can I match lines that start with a specific word?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that currently grabs every line containing the word `ACCOUNT`. How can I only grab the lines that contain the word `ACCOUNT` at the beginning of the line?

```
use strict;

my $find = 'ACCOUNT';

open (NEW, ">", "output.txt" ) or die "could not open:$!";
open (FILE, "<", "Report.txt") or die "could not open:$!";

while (<FILE>) {
    print NEW if (/$find/);
}

close (FILE);
close (NEW);
```

Comment: At the very beginning only, or is it okay if there is whitespace and then "ACCOUNT"?

Comment: This isn't at all hard. I am sure there will be many people lining up to claim their ten points for giving you the answer, but what have you done to find the answer yourself? Google is a handy tool

Comment: I agree with @Borodin. The [answer](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) is [out there](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), and it's not very hard to [find](https://regex101.com).

Comment: @Borodin isn't it 15 points? :)

Comment: @simbabque: I think it's 10 points for each upvote, plus another 10 points for the green tick; but I'm far from certain. I found the points system was getting in the way of me writing good solutions, so I started ignoring it about three years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commented the white space version since people doesn't seem to read comments.

```
use strict;
my $find = 'ACCOUNT';

open (NEW, ">", "output.txt" ) or die "could not open:$!";
open (FILE, "<", "Report.txt") or die "could not open:$!";

while (<FILE>) {
    # print NEW if $_ =~ /^\s*$find/ ; # Any line that starts with whitespace and followed by $find
    print NEW if $_ =~ /^$find/    ; # Any line that starts strictly with $find
}
close (FILE);
close (NEW);
```

Comment: This will double print lines that don't have any leading whitespace.

Comment: I know , I intentionally place both version in case he wants to handle white spaces too. As you can see in the comments I placed inside the code.

Comment: Thank you very much Ohad Dahan, this is exactly what I needed.